# Text does not animate only the background layer

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation

I am learning Angular and I stumbled this small issue I cannot fix.

I managed to animate a div (like a snackbar) but the text in the div does not appear or disappear smoothly like the background layer.

Here is an image of how it acts:
[image]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from './myService';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'snackbar',
  templateUrl: './snackbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snackbar.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('shrinkOut', [
      state('inactive', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('* => void', [
        style({ height: '*'}),
        animate(300, style({height: 0}))
      ]),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ height: 0}),
        animate(300, style({height: '*'}))
      ]),
    ]
    )
  ]
})
export class SnackbarComponent {
  constructor(
    public myService: MyService,
  ) { }
}
```

```css
div.snackbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
}
    
div.snackbar.success {
  background-color: #9f5a77;
}
    
div.snackbar.error {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
```

```html
<div class="snackbar {{myService.currentService.type}}" *ngIf="myService.currentService" [@shrinkOut]>
  Some Text
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how to sync the text with the background layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to realize what I did wrong. To make the text animate as well I should use the `transform` property instead of `height` property.

So, `height: '*'` must be replaced with `translateY(0)`; and `height: 0` must be replaced with `translateY(-100%)`

By using `height` I only animated the height of the div.

Answer (score 1):

The `translateY()` CSS function repositions an element vertically on the 2D plane.

As you're using `height`, you're only animating the height of the **div** due to which only background layer animates and not the text.

Let me know if this helps or you're still facing any issues. :)